# Redirect a malformed URL with more than 1 variable

Tags: apache, .htaccess, variables, redirect, malformed

Redirect with "malformed double ?"

I try the following: an old URL that has to be kept alive is formed like this:
/index.php?id=5041?var1=val1&var2=val2&var3=val3

I have to redirec it to something like this:

```
/path1/path2/?id=1234?var1=val1&var2=val2&var3=val3
```

whatever I try - it's either an infinite loop within index.php or it cuts of the rest of the vars after the id. The rest of the string should be simply attached.

ie.

```
#Only if id = 1234
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=1234? [NC]
#get id for variable $1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=(\d+) [NC]
#get rest for variable $2
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} val1=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /path1/path2/?myid=%1&val2=%2
```

Comment: do an `print_r($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])` in php to see what your script is actually receiving.

Comment: Thx hjpotter92 - nice tool!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?id=([^?]+)\?var=([^&]+)&var2=([^&]+)&var3=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /path1/path2/ [QSA,NC,L,R]
```

The condition above

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /id=([^?]+)\?var=([^&]+)&var2=([^&]+)&var3=([^\s]+) [NC
```

checks if /index.php has specific query strings ,redirect it to a new location.

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you so much Starkeen! - If you can recommend a tutorial I'd be happy to get a link.